# How get very low noise output from generic 5v power supplies

Tags: power-supply, noise

I have an this power stage circuit for my sensitive ADC and would like to improve it. This circuit is just straight out from the evaluation module's power circuit of the ADC. maximum current is < 100mA

[image]

During my testing though i have noticed something. My circuit takes in power from a USB C port (No data just power) and with an ordinary USB wall adapter my ADC has a stable reading of 0.001V. With a power from a lab bench supply (A high end one at that) i get a stable reading of 0.00001. The thing i was reading was from a battery operated device completely isolated, so i know for sure that what caused the improvement is the power supply. I did not expect that much of an improvement literally 100x better.

So here i am on a quest to further improve my power stage. What can i do to further improve my power stage? Do note that i cant use very bulky component after the isolation transformer as there will a shielding on the isolated circuit (5mm height clearance). What makes it even harder for me is that i do not have an oscilloscope (or an oscilloscope probe attachment) that can do 10uV measurement. Im pretty much blind beyond the 1mV point.

Any circuits that have been proven to give really low noise supplies? I know for a fact that the current circuit can achieve those numbers, so maybe i just add some pre stage filtering for those nasty 5v wall adapters?

Comment: > an ordinary USB wall adapter ... is noisy. Some added L-C filter is surely needed.

Comment: @Antonio51 can you recomend a L-C circuit?

Comment: Improved readability picture of schematic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQ8NB.png

Comment: It's pretty common to use ferrite beads to "isolate" the digital from the analog supply. Put in series with your 0.1Ω resistors.  You can also add one to the 5v input.

Comment: @Aaron the 0.1 resistors are actually just pcb placeholders incase i want to put ferrites, or  an inline resistor. So yes that can be done easily. But what i just have 2 lp5907 for analog and digital? would that be better?

Comment: @Jakequin You can test this? coupled inductance 1mH  https://i.stack.imgur.com/As7Ek.png

Comment: @Antonio51 it is possible but i will to look for identical 1mH inductors.

Comment: No, coupled inductors. Here a simulation of what one get with this circuit. (to be verified) https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBzgG.png . With inductances, reduction by 30x of ripple.

Comment: @Antonio51 ohhhh, common mode inductors right? i do not thinnk i have one of those, will have to order that along with the next prototype, i will just leave a trace for it on the board.

Comment: @Jakequin Kcoupling to be verified! Seems that 100 uH also could be used ... with 100 uF.

Answer (score 3):

If you have enough voltage headroom and enough physical space, you could put a [capacitance multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance_multiplier) between the rectifiers and the linear regulator.

A capacitance multiplier doesn't actually do what it sounds like it should do. However, it does remove noise from an unregulated supply. It is essentially and active low pass filter. By feeding a smoother voltage into your regulator, you may get less noise out of it. However, your milage may vary.

[image]
(Picture taken from Wikipedia article).

Comment: i still have some room on the board just the vertical space is limited, so i dont have to remake sa shielding. Where would be the best place to do this? I would assume  on the usb input side as the voltage is still 5v there there is still some voltage headroom. So for the transistor selection, it would seem that higher β is better. So i will just find the highest β i can find ?

Comment: Sice the circuit is very low power with the sn6501 need only 350mA of current cant i just place a simpler 100 uF - 10 Ohm RC circuit for a 160Hz  attenuation ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're asking a much bigger question than you realise.  It seems you're measuing an ADC input (what is the ADC?) with its input connected to... GNDiso?  That's not giving you the full story of your "noise floor", because at the very least, any noise lower than 0 V won't be measured (and it's more complicated than that).  Putting AVcc thru a 50% voltage-divider into the ADC's input (so you measure a half-Vcc input) will give you a better picture of what your input noise is.

The PSU based on a USB-wall-plug will be a * switch-mode * PSU, so it will be introducing its own noise profile on its 5V output into S1.  A different brand/model of USB-PSU will yield a different noise profile.  Either way, it's a source of noise that's well above a 'linear' lab bench PSU.

A linear lab bench PSU is like a big gruntier version of a linear voltage regulator (like your LDO2), and it's typically fed via a transformer with multiple secondary taps (various turns ratios) so that the smarts in the bench PSU will constantly adjust which secondary tap it uses (based on what output voltage is required by the user) so that the 'Vin' to its linear regulator will be well above the regulator's drop-out voltage, but no higher than that, so that the linear reg's heat dissipation is minimised (and thus end up with a PSU with the maximum output current spec).  The upshot is that its output is very clean, low noise, and a 100:1 difference in the two scenarios is to be expected.

You could improve things by adding a LC Pi filter on the 5V input into S1 and deal with some of that noise before it goes any further.

You've also got that S1/S2 combo running at its switching frequency creating noise.  At least there you have a fair idea of what the freuqnecy of the noise is and can deliberately target it with specific LCR filtering elements.

You could add more filter caps on the LDO2 input, in parallel with the C15 & C16 you already have. Even better would be to thoroughly read and understand Tom Anderson's awesome article on this topic about PSU input filtering: https://www.tempoautomation.com/toms-circuits/power-supply-filter-design-for-pcb/

But you've also got AVcc and DVdd powered from the same LDO!  So the current spikes of your digital stuff will create inductive drops on your combined AVcc & DVdd rail (they might be sub-nanosecond, but they'll be there), so you're powering your ADC from a less than clean rail.  (And why are you putting AVcc & DVdd thru 0.1-Ohm resistors??)  At the very least it's common to add (another) LC Pi filter from the LDO2 output and that becomes your AVcc rail.  A better solution is to have a separate second LDO dedicated to the analog circuitry, including the ADC's/MCU's AVcc input.

Then there's the Analog Reference input to your ADC (unless you're using an internal reference).  If you're using your combined AVcc / DVdd rail also as your Analog Vref input, then that's also not helping; your LDO2 output also has significant noise which means your Vref is also noisy.  If you're worried about sub-1mV noise performance, then you absolutely want a a discrete referance voltage chip to feed the ADC's Vref input, and that Vref should ideally be powered from that above-suggested separate LDO powering the analog section, not shared with the DVdd.

Of course with any implementation there's PCB design techniques that become much more relevant when you're concerned with low noise performance.

Worst of all, you're trying to optimise something you can't see!  If you don't have a '5+ digit' multimeter or ultra-low-V 'scope, then you're taking the scattergun approach and hoping for the best.  That's not an engineered solution, it's a pot shot :-)

Comment: This is still my first prototype and the circuits are basically ripped out from the evaluation modules and datasheets and well aware there is still a lot to be done.  I am even amazed i was able to get a stable reading of  10uV even with the bench. Since the circuit  is guaranteed that it can reach that number, shouldn't i focus the efforts to filtering the power right at the usb port? It is possible to borrow a scope but its not that easy so i wont do it yet on this revision, i will test the next revision with it.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the wall-wart that feeds the 5 volts on your isolating power supply is quite noisy (CM noise) and, due to parasitic capacitance in the coupling transformer, you end up with quite high voltage and high frequency ripple on your supposedly clean power rails: -

[image]

On the face of it, it shouldn't be a problem except as you move your hand (for example) close to your target (and supposedly isolated) design you'll draw off small differential noise currents that might upset your sensitive ADC. It's quite a common thing to happen. You get this with wall-warts for instance and sometimes you just need to beef up the internal noise reduction capacitors (see below) with external capacitors.

Even if you didn't move your hand towards sensitive parts (to create excessive noise) there will be an underlying residual problem that could be due to high frequency common-mode ripple currents crossing your isolation transformer (a problem that can get worse when you move your sensitive circuit). A solution to try is putting 10 nF capacitors to ground as per this diagram: -

[image]

It's worth a try anyway. You may even need to find a more solid ground connection for terminating the two capacitors. The wall-wart may have really poor CM noise and, it that case, only a clean ground or earth may do the trick.

Wall-warts reduce their output noise by using an internal capacitor from primary to secondary. This is fine for meeting the high-frequency noise specifications imposed on them but, it will also couple regular AC common-mode currents into whatever load is connected on the DC side. So, some experimentation may be needed to find the best compromise.

Comment: PCB wise where would these capacitor be ? In my board there  is a 5mm 1kv isolation strip that is across the whole pcb [just like this](https://imgur.com/SIcmbkC) (Sorry actual circuit is under a soldered can). Wont placing capacitors that connects both sides compromises the isolation?

Comment: You'll have to figure out where they'll go (close to junction of the two diodes and close to centre-tap of secondary is my best suggestion). Regards compromising the isolation yes, of course it compromises the isolation but, only at high frequencies. Now that may still be a problem so, if it is then try 100 pF capacitors. The bottom line is that everything is capacitively coupled so, when you talk about compromising the isolation, it's just a matter of "how much" rather than "is it".

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a variable voltage regulator like one from the LM217 family.  That allows you to put a smoothing capacitor right on the reference voltage that is otherwise an internal noise source.  You should also take care that C16 has low ESR values to reduce ripple before the regulator.  Similarly for C17 (and both should be mounted as close to the voltage regulator as possible).  You might want to add additional bypass capacitors after R13 and R14 to further reduce possible bleed-through of digital supply to analog supply.  Of course, separating AVDD and DVDD more completely is possible by giving each their own voltage regulator.  Depending on the sensitivities of the circuitry you drive with it, you might then want to use an antiparallel pair of diodes between AVDD and DVDD to limit possible voltage differences during power-on/off.

Comment: I do not think the lm217 will be better, I am not sure how much the smoothing capacitor helps but according to the datasheet the lm217 has a _0.003% Output noise voltage_ meaning at 5V the output noise is 15mV. In comparison the lp5907 regulator i use has a Output noise voltage of 0.01mV .

Comment: The LM317 is an excellent noise source.